# How can I ignore a superclass?

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws

I'm trying to write a web service for the `java.util.logging` api. So I wrote a class MyLogRecord that inherits from LogRecord. I annotated this class with JAX-B annotations, including `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` so it would ignore non-annotated fields and properties. When I start up tomcat, I get errors that `java.util.logging.Level` and other `java.util.logging` classes do not have a default constructor, but none of my annotated methods make any reference to the Level class or any of the other `java.util.logging` classes. These are referenced by the parent class.

My sub-class has everything it needs defined. How can I get JAX-B to ignore the parent class completely?

Update: I found [another post on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659872/how-do-i-prevent-jaxb-from-binding-superclass-methods-of-the-xmlrootelement-when), which suggests modifying the parent class. This is obviously not possible because I am extending a `java.util` class. IS there any way to do this without modifying the superclass?

Update2: I found [a thread on java.net](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=13932&tstart=0) for a similar problem. That thread resulted in an [enhancement request](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=133), which was marked as a duplicate of [another issue](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=216), which resulted in the `@XmlTransient` annotation. The comments on these bug reports lead me to believe this is impossible in the current spec.

Comment: Why not use composition instead of inheritance and wrap a LogRecord rather than extend it?

Comment: Having to convert back and forth seems more clumsy than this. I see no reason this shouldn't be possible. My biggest concern is why XmlAccessType.NONE didn't affect the superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark the parent class @XmlTransient.  Since the parent class is in the JRE and cannot be modified by you, you need an alternate mechanism.

The EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) implementation offers a means of representing the metadata as XML that you could use:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/EclipseLink-OXM.XML

You can specify some of the metadata using annotations, and the rest as XML. Below is what your document would look like:

```
<java-types> 

    <java-type name="java.util.logging.LogRecord" xml-transient="true"/>

</java-types>
```