# How to ignore casing of element names in JaxB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

As stated in the title I want to ignore casing of element names in a document.

```
static class XY433 {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "C200")
    String c200;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "C215")
    String c215;

    @XmlAttribute(name="F001")
    String f001;

    @XmlAttribute(name="f001")
    String lcf001; // I want to avoid this duplication
}
```

I tried to use the code posted by Blaise Doughan:

```
private static class ToLowerCaseNamesStreamReaderDelegate extends StreamReaderDelegate {

    public ToLowerCaseNamesStreamReaderDelegate(XMLStreamReader xsr) {
        super(xsr);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeLocalName(int index) {
        return super.getAttributeLocalName(index).toLowerCase();
    }

    @Override
    public String getLocalName() {
        return super.getLocalName().toLowerCase();
    }

}


@XmlRootElement(name="doc")
static class Doc {
    @XmlElement(name="element")
    List<Element> elements;
}

static class Element {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "abc")
    String abc;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("LowerCaseElementNamesFilterTest.xml"));

    Unmarshaller u = JAXBContext.newInstance(Doc.class).createUnmarshaller();

    //Do unmarshalling
    Doc doc = (Doc) u.unmarshal(new ToLowerCaseNamesStreamReaderDelegate(xsr));

    System.out.println(doc.elements.get(0).abc);
    System.out.println(doc.elements.get(1).abc);
    System.out.println(doc.elements.get(2).abc);

}
```

This actually did not work.

```
null
2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:546)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:321)
    at com.hre.commons.tec.xml.LowerCaseElementNamesFilter.main(LowerCaseElementNamesFilter.java:58)
```

For this XML:

```
<doc>
    <Element ABC="1"></Element>
    <element Abc="1"></element>
    <element abc="2"></element>
</doc>
```

Comment: look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType.html#NONE and this queistion is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659872/how-do-i-prevent-jaxb-from-binding-superclass-methods-of-the-xmlrootelement-when :)

Comment: How is my question related to this super class question? How can I use the AccessType? My question is about f001 and lcf001. I just want one field bound to "F001" and "f001".

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to override the case-sensitive nature of XML? Is it because you are not in control of the incoming data?

Comment: Yes, it is produced from a legacy application.

Comment: And even the wsdl allows it by defining each element in all cases. :-(

Comment: Oh my; I've actually read "casing" -> "casting" and made wrong assumptions from that :/ my apologies.

Comment: @tkr:  I have tried your code in my environment and everything works as expected, see update.  In my updated I've also specified what implementations/versions I'm using.  There could be something in your setup causing a problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could map all your properties to lower case node names, and then wrap an XMLStreamReader to call toLowerCase() on all attribute/element names it returned.  Then unmarshal from that XMLStreamReader.

I have recently added an enhance request for EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) for this issue, feel free to provide additional information:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331241

**Object Model**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;

    @XmlAttribute
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}


public class Address {

    private String street;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

}
```

**Demo Code**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("input.xml"));
        xsr = new MyStreamReaderDelegate(xsr);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

    private static class MyStreamReaderDelegate extends StreamReaderDelegate {

        public MyStreamReaderDelegate(XMLStreamReader xsr) {
            super(xsr);
        }

        @Override
        public String getAttributeLocalName(int index) {
            return super.getAttributeLocalName(index).toLowerCase();
        }

        @Override
        public String getLocalName() {
            return super.getLocalName().toLowerCase();
        }

    }

}
```

Will read these XML documents:

```
<CUSTOMER ID="1">
    <NAME>Jane Doe</NAME>
    <ADDRESS>
        <STREET>123 A Street</STREET>
    </ADDRESS>
</CUSTOMER>

<CuSToMeR Id="1">
    <NaMe>Jane Doe</NAME>
    <AdDrEsS>
        <STREET>123 A Street</STREET>
    </AdDRrEsS>
</CuSToMeR>
```

And write the following XML:

```
<customer id="1">
   <address>
      <street>123 A Street</street>
   </address>
   <name>Jane Doe</name>
</customer>
```

Below is a link to a more detailed example:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/case-insensitive-unmarshalling.html

**UPDATE**

Your code works in my environment (JDK 1.6.0_20 with both the included JAXB, and EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) 2.2, I'm also using the default implementation of StAX).  When I run your example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate;

public class Example {

    private static class ToLowerCaseNamesStreamReaderDelegate extends StreamReaderDelegate {

        public ToLowerCaseNamesStreamReaderDelegate(XMLStreamReader xsr) {
            super(xsr);
        }

        @Override
        public String getAttributeLocalName(int index) {
            return super.getAttributeLocalName(index).toLowerCase();
        }

        @Override
        public String getLocalName() {
            return super.getLocalName().toLowerCase();
        }

    }


    @XmlRootElement(name="doc")
    static class Doc {
        @XmlElement(name="element")
        List<Element> elements;
    }

    static class Element {
        @XmlAttribute(name = "abc")
        String abc;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("LowerCaseElementNamesFilterTest.xml"));

        Unmarshaller u = JAXBContext.newInstance(Doc.class).createUnmarshaller();

        //Do unmarshalling
        Doc doc = (Doc) u.unmarshal(new ToLowerCaseNamesStreamReaderDelegate(xsr));

        System.out.println(doc.elements.get(0).abc);
        System.out.println(doc.elements.get(1).abc);
        System.out.println(doc.elements.get(2).abc);

    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
1
1
2
```

**UPDATE #2**

To address:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException -
>   with linked exception:
>   [javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:
>   Namespace URIs and local names to the
>   unmarshaller needs to be interned.] at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:425)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:362)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:332)

Have you tried modifying the delegate?:

```
@Override
public String getAttributeLocalName(int index) {
    return super.getAttributeLocalName(index).toLowerCase().intern();
}

@Override
public String getLocalName() {
    return super.getLocalName().toLowerCase().intern();
}
```

Comment: XmlStreamReader has ca 40 methods to implement. Is there any base class I could use?

Comment: Check out:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/util/StreamReaderDelegate.html

Comment: Running with <customer Id="1">... will result in customer.id==0

Comment: Running with your all capitals example will raise:

Comment: @tkr:  I have tried your code in my environment and get the expected output.  Could you provide more details about your environment?  My update contains the versions and implementations of JDK, StAX and JAXB I'm using.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Namespace URIs and local names to the unmarshaller needs to be interned.]
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:425)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:362)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:332)

Comment: @tkr - In my second update I have added a modification that may solve this issue.

Comment: @Override
        public String getAttributeLocalName(int index) {
            return super.getAttributeLocalName(index).toLowerCase().intern();
            // Intern fixes the issue. Is this a good solution?
        }

Comment: Using intern() in my example for my configuration solves the issues too. Although there was no excpetion regarding the interning.

Comment: Do you know whether it is a good idea to intern all local names?

Comment: Without looking at it too deeply, for this use case I would only do enough interning to make that exception go away :).  I'm happy everything is working for you now.

Comment: Blaise Doughan's solution with the ".intern()" addendum worked wonderfully for me. Really helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: One more question, how to ignore case sensitive of the a node's value? I tried overwritting the getText(), but it cannot solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am using moxy 2.7.1 version and it is working fine with UnmarshallerProperty as below.

```
unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.UNMARSHALLING_CASE_INSENSITIVE, true);
```

[eclipselink documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/JAXBContextProperties.html#UNMARSHALLING_CASE_INSENSITIVE)

Answer (score 1):

Encounter the similar problem.
My solution is to add `@XmlAdpater` on the model entity, which refers to your own `XMLAdapter`, this would give a flexible customization on the marshall/unmarshall.