# How to ignore casing of xmlAttribute setters/getters in JaxB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have followed this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375176/how-to-ignore-casing-of-element-names-in-jaxb) and I am able to ignore the case when input xml has variable name casing.

However, when my Java variables have a camelCase name, I write the getters and setters as getCamelCase and setCamelCase, however the expected getters/setters are getCamelcase and setCamelcase.

The only way to have {g,s}etCamelCase is to specify the @XmlAttribute(name = "camelcase") above the getters/setters.

I think reflection of the methods in my class treats the methods as case sensitive. Is there any way to avoid having to add the @XmlAttribute(name = "camelcase")

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "blah")
public class Blah {

    String listName;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "listname")  // without "listname" the attribute is not set.
    public String getListName() {
        return listName;
    }
    public void setListName(String listName) {
        this.listName = listName;
    }
}
```

Driver code.

```
    String filename = "blah.xml";
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename));
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Blah.class).createUnmarshaller();
    Blah blah = (Blah) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new ToLowerCaseNamesStreamReaderDelegate(xsr));
    System.out.println("blah.getListname() = " + blah.getListName());
```

Comment: It's just a guess, but if you used that `toLowerCase()` trick I believe, your method name should be `getListname` not `getListaName`...

Comment: @Betlista, getListname works. I am wondering whether these is a similar trick/adapter for method names.