# Ebean enhancement is messing up JAXB serialization

Tags: java, jaxb, playframework-2.0, ebean

In our Play application we use Ebean ORM. We have model classes that used to inherit from a Play Model class. Since Play 2.4 our model classes have to inherit from the Avaje Ebean Model class. These model classes are enhanced, i.e. several methods are injected into our model classes. Since this change we get JAXB error messages saying for example:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.avaje.ebean.bean.PersistenceContext is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.avaje.ebean.bean.PersistenceContext
        at public com.avaje.ebean.bean.PersistenceContext com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept.getPersistenceContext()
        at com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept
        at protected com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept models.Phase._ebean_intercept
        at models.Phase
```

I tried to work around this by adding this to the Phase model class:

```
@XmlTransient
public EntityBeanIntercept _ebean_intercept() {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
};
```

Unfortunately this trick doesn't work and results in the error message "Duplicate method name&signature in class file models/Phase". Is there another way of telling JAXB to ignore the enhanced members of this class?

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer on this post [How do I prevent JAXB from binding superclass methods of the @XmlRootElement when marshalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659872/how-do-i-prevent-jaxb-from-binding-superclass-methods-of-the-xmlrootelement-whe) is saying that this is not possible, there is a second answer that provides a workaround in some cases.

I'm guessing that that new superclass doesn't live in the same package as your model classes though, so you might be out of luck :-(